# What is a good word for filling in the following blank: "Insecurity has a million ways of ______ itself"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, verbs

I am looking for a better word than "presenting". I cannot remember this word exactly. The word I am trying to remember is frequently used when talking about apparitions or supernatural beings. Like

> Amongst the densest of rain clouds a fire breathing dragon _______ itself.

The same word could be used here also. This is something I cannot google my way out of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Insecurity has a million ways of [manifesting](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/manifest) itself. Not sure about dragons.